# Web Service HTTP Headers

Tags: java, web-services, soap, http-headers, authorization

I'm having trouble adding a HTTP custom header to my web service request. I need to have a header called "Authorization" and with a constant value of "Bearer token_id" but I can't figure out how to do this.

Using SoapUI I could add it by pressing the "Add custom HTTP Header" button, and it worked perfectly, but now I need to implement it in my custom class.

This is the part where I need to add my header:

```
        try {
            //SERVICE
            Service service = new Service();
            Call call = (Call) service.createCall();    
            call.setTargetEndpointAddress(new java.net.URL(endPointURL));
            call.setSOAPActionURI(soapActionURI);

                /*
                MessageContext msgContext= call.getMessageContext();
                MimeHeaders hd = msgContext.getMessage().getMimeHeaders();
                hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token_id");
                */


             System.out.println("Authorization WS");

            //INVOKE
            SOAPEnvelope response = (SOAPEnvelope) call.invoke(new Message(soap.asXML()));
            Document doc = new DOMReader().read(response.getAsDocument());          
            return doc;

        }
```

The following is the console output:

```
Authorization WS
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (401)Unauthorized
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {}:return code:  401
&lt;soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot;&gt;&lt;faultcode xmlns:axis2ns18=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot;&gt;axis2ns18:Client&lt;/faultcode&gt;&lt;faultstring&gt;Authentication Failure&lt;/faultstring&gt;&lt;detail&gt;Required OAuth credentials not provided&lt;/detail&gt;&lt;/soapenv:Fault&gt;
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HttpErrorCode:401

(401)Unauthorized
```

If I execute the commented part I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error at the `MimeHeaders hd = msgContext.getMessage().getMimeHeaders();` line

Comment: at which line in the commentaries do you get a null pointer?

Comment: sorry, this is the line: `MimeHeaders hd = msgContext.getMessage().getMimeHeaders();`

Answer (score 0):

How about setting the message first ? Something like:

```
MessageContext msgContext= call.getMessageContext();
msgContext.setMessage(new Message(soap.asXML()));
MimeHeaders hd = msgContext.getMessage().getMimeHeaders();
hd.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer token_id");
```

Since you must set the message before the header.

Comment: I still get unauthorized:  `faultCode: {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}HTTP
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: (401)Unauthorized`

Comment: @GiLA3 So you don't get a NPE anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You might try this workaround:

1. Use Postman to make the SOAP request.
2. Enter the wsdl and click the Headers tab.
3. Enter your headers, including "Authorization" under the heading
   "Key." Under "Value" type "Bearer " and then paste your token id.
4. Make the request (I think it is POST for SOAP).
5. If successful, you can click the "Code" button in Postman and it
   will display the header in your request in your selected language.